# How can I have a gridview work horizontally in UWP?

Tags: gridview, uwp

I have a Gridview where I want items to be grouped and flow horizontally. The groups are still vertically scrolling. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you give us a sample as to how the gridview looks?

Comment: Did you check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477919/vertically-scrolling-gridview-xaml-windows-store-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ItemsPanelTemplate is the one that determines the layout of items. Usually an ItemsWrapGrid is used for a GridView. That control has a property called MaximumRowsOrColumns. Set that to the number of rows you want as a max on a page. The data is then always in a horizontal layout. You can add something like this:

```
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: This will not support ISupportIncrementalLoading

Answer (score 1):

> The groups are still vertically scrolling. How can I fix this?

I think you have done the "group-items" part work. So your problem is how to make the grouped items lay horizontal and make the `GridView` can horizontally scroll. To do this, you can set the `ItemsWrapGrid` of the `GridView` to vertical `Orientation`, for example like this:

```xml
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Header" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Key}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </GridView.GroupStyle>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```