# I want to implement Adaptive Horizontal ListView in UWP-XAML

Tags: listview, uwp

I want to implement Adaptive Horizontal ListView in UWP-XAML, like below image.
Currently I have no idea how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given that the content in your image is to be picture-heavy, you'd be better off using a [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview). But the answer to your question will work for both GridView and ListView, so it shouldn't matter.

To make the ListView items stack horizontally, you adjust the orientation of the ItemsWrapGrid, as so:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="1" Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

This will give you a horizontally-orientated ListView of one row.
To get the horizontal scroll bar, change the properties of the ListView's ScrollViewer:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="1" Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

By disabling vertical scroll, we allow the mouse to scroll horizontally instead of vertically. And if you want to use a GridView, the above will work perfectly too. Just change the ListView tags to GridView tags. [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37960061/5772047) has a good example of using a GridView.